# Apply CSS `backdrop-filter` to polygon shape

Tags: javascript, html, css

As per the two images below, I'm trying to create a "tooltip" with a statically sized triangle on the bottom. However, I want to apply `backdrop-filter: blur(10px);` to the entire shape. Currently the blur filter only applies to the rectangle and not the triangle.

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.Tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  overflow: visible;
}

.Tooltip::before {
  background: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.3);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  width: 20px;
}

.RedBar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="RedBar"></div>
<div class="Tooltip"></div>
```

**The shape:**
[image: Illustration of the shape]

**The problem:**
[image: Illustration of the problem]

Comment: Can you please add code to make it a minimal example?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to solve this (since I guess the `backdrop-filter` property is not supported (yet) while using pseudo elements) is to make the tooltip background a `clip-path`, so it's the shape of the tooltip. See below snippet for the code and check the full screen example.

A sidenote: your CSS was failing due to the incorrect declaration of `rgba()`. You cannot add a hex color to it. F.e. `rgba(#555555, 0.3);` is wrong, it should be `rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.3)`, since it's the rgb code you need to write down.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.Tooltip {
  position: fixed;
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 75%, 58% 76%, 49% 83%, 40% 75%, 0% 75%);
  overflow: visible;
  color: #fff;
}

.RedBar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 250px;
  left: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 30px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="RedBar"></div>
<div class="Tooltip">lentesque efficitur interdum elit, vel euismod lorem rutrum non. Etiam congue tortor rhoncus velit pharetra, nec ornare lacus hendrerit. Phasellus malesuada tellus at enim porttitor commodo. Curabitur commodo lacus erat, sit amet pretium sapien rutrum in. Cras vitae tortor nunc. Praesent elementum, massa at rhoncus ultrices, ligula dui finibus risus, sed sollicitudin orci neque sit amet libero. Ut volutpat urna id</div>
```

**EDIT**
Another outcome with adding an extra `div` that mimics as the triangle inside the tooltip. Still not the ideal solution.

```css
body {
  background: black;
  min-height: 500px;
}

.tooltip-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  background: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.3);
  box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
  overflow: visible;
  color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tooltip-arrow {
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 50% 100%);
  background: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.3);
  width: 20px;
  height: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
}

.RedBar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 210px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="RedBar"></div>
<div class="tooltip-wrapper">
  <div class="tooltip">lentesque efficitur interdum elit, vel euismod lorem rutrum non. Etiam congue tortor rhoncus velit pharetra, nec ornare lacus hendrerit. Phasellus malesuada tellus at enim porttitor commodo. Curabitur commodo lacus erat, sit amet pretium sapien rutrum
    Phasellus malesuada tellus at enim porttitor commodo. Curabitur commodo lacus erat, sit amet pretium sapien rutrum in. Cras vitae tortor nunc. Praesent elementum, massa at rhoncus ultrices, ligula dui finibus risus, sed sollicitudin orci neque sit
    amet libero. Ut volutpat urna id</div>
  <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `clip-path` such that the triangle is always the same size regardless of the tooltip size?

Comment: @HunterLarco I updated the answer with another take: add an extra div that is the arrow only. As you can see, still not the optimal solution, but at least better scalable.